# Add custom menu item to sales menu tab in magento 2 admin sidebar with example page

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I study Magento 2, within 2 weeks, and such a task appeared.

I need to add a custom tab to the sales sidebar, maybe someone has already encountered such a task?

Comment: Hi Geriht. What do you mean exactly? An extra tab on order detail page in the admin? Or in the customer account?

Comment: In the admin panel we have a sales field, I need to add a new field to it by order type

Comment: Oh, you mean in the menu, like this: https://prnt.sc/1o0r324?

Comment: Yes? do u know how ?

Comment: Yes, check my answer. That should work and add a menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a menu item to the Magento 2 admin with a default landing page, add these files and adjust to your own needs. This will create a Custom Menu item under sales menu tab with an example page.

app/code/Company/Module/registration.php

```php
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Company/Module/etc/module.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Module/etc/acl.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales">
                    <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales_operation">
                        <resource id="Company_Module::custommenu" title="Custom Menu" sortOrder="10"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Company_Module::custommenu"
             title="Custom Menu"
             module="Company_Module"
             sortOrder="100"
             parent="Magento_Sales::sales_operation"
             action="custommenu/index/index"
             resource="Company_Module::custommenu"
        />
    </menu>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="custommenu" frontName="custommenu">
            <module name="Company_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

```php
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Company_Module::custommenu');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Custom Menu'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Company_Module::custommenu');
    }
}
```

app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/custommenu_index_index.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Company_Module::content.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/content.phtml

```html
<p>Content goes here</p>
```

After adding the files, run following command from the command line: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Good luck. Please let me know if it works out. You can check the answer as accepted then.

Comment: When i press on my tab exist this error Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.

Comment: Hi Geriht. Glad the menu item appears. But it has no content yet, that's why you get this message. I've added some files as example so you get a default page.